# Docker dynamic load balancing with Nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, load-balancing

I'm doing an internship focused on Docker and I have to load-balance an application which have a client, a server and a database. I use Nginx as a load-balancer and my goal is to dynamically scale the number of server containers according their CPU usage. For instance if the CPU usage is over 60% I want to add a new container on the fly without restarting Nginx to divide the CPU usage. 
I have to modify the nginx.conf file to add a new container but I have to restart the Nginx container to apply the changes, which is very slow.

So my question is : is there a (free) way to do it dynamically ?

Tell me if you want further information and forgive my poor english.
Thanks.

**EDIT :** I did as @Konstantin Azizov told me :

```
docker cp ./new.conf $(docker ps -f "name=dockerizedrubis_nginx" -q ):/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
docker exec $(docker ps -f "name=dockerizedrubis_nginx" -q) bash -c 'kill -HUP $(cat /run/nginx.pid)'
docker exec $(docker ps -f "name=dockerizedrubis_nginx" -q) bash -c '/etc/init.d/nginx reload'
```

The configuration file is well pasted in the container supporting Nginx, I send the HUP signal to reconfigure the Nginx process et then I reload to apply my changes. There are no errors and the reload on-the-fly works fine but my new nodes are not taken into account by Nginx, the requests are still only directed to the first node created ...

**EDIT 2 :** I found the origin of the problem. It seems like in order to update the /etc/hosts of a container after a 'docker-compose scale', this container needs to be stopped, removed and restarted. In my case, I really don't want to stop the container supporting Nginx.

**Question :** Anyone has an idea of how to update /etc/hosts of a container after a re-scale without having to restart the container (beside a dirty script) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the nginx-proxy image from [Json Wilder](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) for a while to load balance between containers, and it works for more than one scalable service. It monitors the docker daemon and if an event happens it rebuilds the nginx config file adding the new container instances when you are scaling out or removing it if you are scaling in.

Since Docker 1.10 (not sure if this is the correct version) there is a internal DNS embedded into Docker daemon, so since then I am using the round robin feature from it. Now I am using the oficial nginx image to proxy pass the requests to the a domain that I define as alias into network options. I do not know if I was clear due to my poor english but I believe my [Github](https://github.com/wsilva/docker-lb-demo) example may help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy(free) way to change configuration without restarting, the only way to achieve zero-downtime scaling it's graceful restart, when you restarting Nginx gracefully it will spawn new instance with new configuration wait until it boots up and then kill old instance with the previous configuration.

See [official guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/#upgrading-to-a-new-binary-on-the-fly).